# React DropdownButton issues and alternatives

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

This DropdownButton for React Bootstrap is driving me crazy. I have it working, onSelect I'm firing a callback that gets the selected item, no problem.

The issue I'm seeing is that on hover, the items show, but when you try to move your mouse onto them, the mouse moves over the space between the dropdown itself and the items, and the dropdown closes every time you try to hover and select. You have to actually click and then select which would be confusing to the user.

Also on select, the menu stays open which I might be able to manipulate using the state and setting the open property.

I'm just wondering if there's a way to avoid the menu closing when you hover over the dropdown, and if not are there any alternatives to use for a dropdown with react and/or bootstrap?

**Edit:**

The code is the standard dropdownbutton from the ReactBootstrap website -

```
<ButtonToolbar>
  <DropdownButton title="Default button" id="dropdown-size-medium">
    <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem divider />
    <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
  </DropdownButton>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

Comment: Cant help without seeing your code or an example.

Comment: @ZimSystem the code is the same code from the React-Bootstrap website

Comment: why are the items shown when you are on hover ? this not seems to be the default behavier of a DropdownButton, did you add some customizations ?

Comment: @oliv37 No customizations. I thought the same thing, it works on the React-Bootstrap website but in my application it does not, I'm not sure if this is due to patches or an update or something, perhaps the version I have is not the same as the website.

Comment: hard to find where does the problem come from without the full app, did you correctly add `bootstrap.css` and `react-bootstrap` library ?

Comment: @stratg5, well which version do you have? Also, when you say hover you actually mean placing the cursor on the dropdown option?